# How to remove multiple headers(CTS, referral policy and etc) in web.config in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to remove multiple headers from `web.config` if they are added from startup and also added from `web.config` file. If a header already exists, then I do not want to add it again from `web.config` file.